# Why i can not use the same variable with JS and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why can't I use the same variable with JS and jQuery?
for example:

```
var elHTML = '<div></div>';
var el = document.getElementById('elementFirst'); //js code
el.innerHTML = elHTML; //js code
//it works!
```

if i change some code like this..

```
var elHTML = '<div></div>';
var el = $('#elementFirst'); //jQuery code
el.innerHTML = elHTML; //js code
//not work!
```

or this

```
var elHTML = '<div></div>';
var el = document.getElementById('elementFirst'); //js code
el.html(elHTML); //jQuery code
//not work!
```

and nothing happened with `#elementFirst` in last two codes

thanks for answering in advance

Comment: You can't mix them document.getElementById() returns an HTML element and $() return jQuery Object. There structure and associated methods are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `$()` returns you not an `HTMLElement`, but an `DOM element` wrapped with `jQuery object`.
jQuery's functions can be used only with `jQuery objects`.

In the 2nd case, you use `innerHTML` property, which does not exist in the jQuery's object.

In the 3rd case, you use `html()` function, which is a jQuery function, but you have used it with `HTMLElement`.

**See examples.**

You can see that `innerHTML` property does not exist in `jQuery object` and `html` function in `DOM element`.

```js
var jEl = $('#elementFirst');
console.log('innerHTML' in jEl);

var domEl = document.getElementById('elementFirst');
console.log('html' in domEl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='elementFirst'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var elHTML = '<div>Hello</div>';
var el = $('#elementFirst'); //jQuery code
el.get(0).innerHTML = elHTML;
```

Basically you use .get(0) to transition away from jQuery to plain vanilla JavaScript